# Active Directory different results for DirectorySearcher and PrincipalSearcher

Tags: c#, search, active-directory

I have strange problem when querying Active Directory in C#.

```
var ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "adr", "usr", "pwd");
var entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + adr, usr, pwd);

var searcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry) { Filter = "(&(sAMAccountName=user_to_search))", PageSize = 2000 };

foreach (SearchResult searchUser in searcher.FindAll())
{
    // groups
    var groups = searchUser.GetPropertyValues("memberof");
}

var groups = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "usr_to_search").GetGroups(ctx).ToList();
```

But the results are not the same:

- the `PrincipalSearcher` returns 14 groups
- the `DirectorySearcher` returns 12 groups

Well, is this bug or did I miss something?

Thanks

Comment: Well, can you find out **which** two groups the `PrincipalSearcher` returns additionally?? I believe the `PrincipalSearcher` will also return what is known as the "primary group" of a user - which is **not** returned by the `DirectorySearcher` code. But what that second group is - no idea. Try to list out the results for both searches and post the results here! I'm most interested in seeing the results!

Comment: Primary group - interesting idea , the second group is Domain Users (global unit). Well, is here any chance to load primary group with directory searcher?

Comment: Well, the `Domain Users` is the default "primary group" for user accounts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh my god, i have mistake in my extension method ( **i < prop.count - 1**).

```
 public static List<string> GetPropertyValues(this SearchResult searchResult,string property)
        {
            var prop = searchResult.Properties[property];
            var results = new List<string>();


            if (prop != null && prop.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < prop.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    results.Add(prop[i].ToString());
                }
            }
            return results;
        }
```

Sorry for stupid question.